# Why can't I access a superclass' enum in Kotlin?

Tags: java, android, enums, kotlin, subclass

I am converting a Java Android project to Kotlin.

I am using [API.AI's client](https://github.com/api-ai/apiai-android-client), which has two `AIConfiguration` classes:

*Superclass*

```
package ai.api;
public class AIConfiguration implements Cloneable {
     public static enum SupportedLanguages {
         English("en"),
         //...
     }
         //...
}
```

*Subclass*

```
package ai.api.android;
public class AIConfiguration extends ai.api.AIConfiguration {
    public enum RecognitionEngine {
    //...
}
```

In my Java code, I was creating an instance of the subclass, as recommended in the api guide:

```
final AIConfiguration config = new AIConfiguration("TOKEN",
        AIConfiguration.SupportedLanguages.English,
        AIConfiguration.RecognitionEngine.System);
```

Once converted to Kotlin, it looks like this:

```
val config = AIConfiguration("TOKEN",
        AIConfiguration.SupportedLanguages.English,
        AIConfiguration.RecognitionEngine.System)
```

...which causes an **`Unresolved reference: SupportedLanguages`**.

- I can update the reference to `ai.api.AIConfiguration.SupportedLanguages.English`, which compiles successfully.
- I could import the superclass with `import ai.api.AIConfiguration as SuperAIConfiguration` and use `SuperAIConfiguration.SupportedLanguages`, but I would rather reference the enum directly on the subclass.

I don't get it: **why is this reference valid in Java but not in Kotlin?**

Comment: Did you check your imports? it sounds like the conversion drops some imports, that is probably why using the full reference works

Comment: @Brian: I'm still importing the subclass (on which references work fine like `AIConfiguration.RecognitionEngine.System`), however I cannot do `Subclass.SUPER_CLASS_ENUM` anymore. Is this a specificity of the Kotlin language, not forwarding enum references to subclasses?

Comment: Kotlin does not have a concept of static classes, it creates companion objects to the class to allow the fields to be accessed. The companion object is enclosed in the class, i will need to verify why the companion object is being passed in. The problem may simply be the use of the ambiguous file name: as you can see code works when you use the full file reference

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The visibility rules in Kotlin are different from those in Java. Kotlin classes do not "inherit" static nested classes from supertypes, because the rules get too complicated when companion objects come into play. We are trying to keep the rules as simple as possible, and normally there's no issue accessing a nested class through a supertype name, but in your case the short names of the subclass and superclass clash. This is not typical, so you have the options you listed in the question: a fully-qualified name or a rename on import.

Comment: I'm noticing your answer a few years late, but really appreciate you giving some insights on the thought process behind this! I surely appreciate this Keep it simple mindset, one of the key reasons behind Kotlin's awesomeness.